# Direct2D - Nothing is being drawn to the screen, something wrong in the way I'm handling arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, garbage-collection, direct2d

Hello everyone and thank you for looking. This is a follow up to the original question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474943/how-can-i-create-a-random-number-of-d2d-shapes-rectangles-and-ellipses-and-refe).

I have a base class that I define thusly:

```
class DrawableShape
{
public:
    virtual HRESULT DrawShape(ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* m_pRenderTarget)
    {
        return S_OK;
    }
};
```

I have two classes that extend this class, both are similar, so I'm listing one:

```
class MyD2DEllipse : public DrawableShape
{
private:
    D2D1_ELLIPSE data;
public:
    MyD2DEllipse();
    HRESULT DrawShape(ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* m_pRenderTarget);
};
```

The DrawShape function is implemented like this:

```
HRESULT MyD2DEllipse::DrawShape(ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* m_pRenderTarget)
{
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    ID2D1SolidColorBrush* m_pBrush;
    hr = m_pRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(
                D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::OrangeRed),
                &m_pBrush
                );
    m_pRenderTarget->DrawEllipse(&data, m_pBrush, 10.f);
    return hr;
}
```

I want to draw a random number of ellipses and rectangles to the screen, so I first find out those random numbers, create an array of DrawableShape with that size (since I can't allocate objects dynamically in C++), replace the parent objects with the child objects, and then call the draw function on the array, randomly again. Here's what my code looks like:

```
    HRESULT Demo::OnRender()
    {
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;
        hr = CreateDeviceResources();

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            m_pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
            m_pRenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());
            m_pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White));

            // Decide on # of primitives
        randEllipse = 1 + (rand() % 5);
        randRectangle = 1 + (rand() % 5);
        totalPrimitives = randEllipse + randRectangle;

        DrawableShape *shapes;
        shapes = new MyShape[totalPrimitives];

        for (int i=0; i<randEllipse; i++)
        {
            MyEllipse ellipse1;
            shapes[i] = ellipse1;
        }
        for (int i=randEllipse; i<(randEllipse + randRectangle); i++)
        {
            MyRectangle rect1;
            shapes[i] = rect1;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<totalPrimitives; i++)
        {
            hr = shapes[i].DrawMyShape(m_pRenderTarget);
        }
        hr = m_pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
    }
}
```

That should've worked, but it doesn't. Also, after writing this out, I realize that I'm better off creating the array in some sort of init function, and calling the draw on the array in the OnRender function. Please help!!

---

EDIT: Okay I've got the shapes working with pointers, the problem is the construction of the array. So I have something like this:

```
    MyD2DRectangle rect1;
    MyD2DEllipse ell1;

    DrawableShape *shape1 = &rect1;
    DrawableShape *shape2 = &ell1;
    shape1->DrawShape(m_pRenderTarget);
    shape2->DrawShape(m_pRenderTarget);
```

That seems to work by itself. How can I create the array of DrawableShape without slicing?

Comment: You can't create an array of MyShape, only MyShape* if you're trying to avoid slicing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shapes` is an array of `MyShape` instances.  When you say `shapes[i] = ellipse1;` or `shapes[i] = rect1;`, you are losing the subclass data as part of this assignment, which is known as [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) in C++.

As such, each call to `shapes[i].DrawMyShape(m_pRenderTarget);` is just returning `S_OK` as defined in `MyShape`.

In order to properly use polymorphism in C++, you need to use pointers or references to `MyShape` instances (usually allocated using `new`).  If you are not allowed to do this (homework?), then you need to find a way to do this without polymorphism.

Comment: Okay, slicing makes perfect sense. Now, while I am allowed to use pointers, I'm not exactly comfortable around them. Could you suggest syntactic examples/share some links on the correct usage? Thanks James.

Comment: This link will probably explain it better than I can.  http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

Comment: Right, as Mark Ransom said, instead of using an array of `MyShape`, make `DrawableShape **shapes = new MyShape*[totalPrimitives]`.  Then you have an array of `MyShape*`, not an array of `MyShape`.

Comment: Lol, just figured that out, thanks.... I'll edit the question with my final answer once I have it. I'm marking your answer as the right one. Thanks for all the help, James :)

Comment: No problem.  I remember struggling with pointers once.  It will pass.  Just keep working at it. :)

Comment: btw, I used DrawableShape* shapes[totalPrimitives]; instead of DrawableShape **shapes = new DrawableShape*[totalPrimitives]; Both statements work, so what's the difference?

Comment: The first allocates the memory on the local stack, whereas the second is allocated to the heap. Yours is probably the better solution for how it was being used.

Comment: Aaaah, correction. I used DrawableShape* shapes[2]; When I replace that with DrawableShape* shapes[totalPrimitives]; I get an error saying "expected constant expression, cannot allocate an array of constant size 0. 'shapes' unknown size." Looks like I'll be allocating to the heap.